# theme("pager") returns NULL

Tags: 6, paging

I am trying to use theme_pager to create pagination as below, but pagination does not appear. I have tried using `var_dump(theme('pager', NULL, 10))` and the result is `NULL`.

```
$q="SELECT DISTINCT(node.nid) AS nid, node.type AS node_type, node.vid AS node_vid, node.title AS node_title, node.language AS node_language, node.created AS node_created, node_revisions.teaser AS node_revisions_teaser, node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format FROM node node  LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid WHERE (node.type in ('slideshow')) AND (node.status <> 0) AND (node.language='$lang') GROUP BY nid ORDER BY node_created DESC";
$result = pager_query($q, 10, 0);
//Process data.
return $output . theme('pager', NULL, 10);
```

also i tried to simplify the query and to make it from one table as below, but this didn't work as well

```
SELECT nid, title, language, created FROM node WHERE node.type='slideshow' AND node.status  0 AND node.language='en' ORDER BY created DESC
```

Any idea is highly appreciated!

Comment: Have you checked that the query actually returns more results than the pager limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the query that is probably too complex, and `pager_query()` cannot alter it to obtain the total number of row matching the query passed as argument.
As reported in the documentation for [pager_query()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--pager.inc/function/pager_query/6):

> The pager uses LIMIT-based queries to fetch only the records required to render a certain page. However, **it has to learn the total number of records returned by the query to compute the number of pages** (the number of records / records per page). This is done by inserting `COUNT(*)` in the original query. For example, the query `SELECT nid, type FROM node WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY sticky DESC, created DESC` would be rewritten to read `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY sticky DESC, created DESC`. Rewriting the query is accomplished using a regular expression.
>
> **Unfortunately, the rewrite rule does not always work as intended for queries that already have a `COUNT(*)` or a `GROUP BY` clause, and possibly for other complex queries.** In those cases, **you can optionally pass a query that will be used to count the records**.
>
> For example, if you want to page the query `SELECT COUNT(*), TYPE FROM node GROUP BY TYPE`, `pager_query()` would invoke the incorrect query `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node GROUP BY TYPE`. So instead, you should pass `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(TYPE)) FROM node` as the optional `$count_query` parameter.

Comment: I have simplified the query to be:
SELECT node.nid AS nid, node.title AS node_title, node.language AS node_language, node.created AS node_created FROM node WHERE (node.type = 'slideshow') AND (node.status <> 0) AND (node.language='en') GROUP BY nid ORDER BY node_created DESC
and this didn't fix the issue

Comment: by removing the prefix (node.) everything works fine :D Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Probably your `$countquery` is not working properly.

You can try with the following code.

```
pager_query($query, 15, 0, $countQuery);
```